# Cloud Firestore Realtime Data

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im researching Cloud Firestore(Java project) and i've got a question.
In firestore collection(VIN)/document(VIN_NUMBER)/fields data structure, I am subscribing to get realtime updates on the database with code as below:

```
firestore.collection(FirestoreGateway.FIRESTORE_COLLECTION_FLAT)
                .addSnapshotListener((snapshots, e) -> {
                    if (e != null) {
                        System.err.println("Listen failed: " + e);
                        return;
                    }

                    for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                        switch (dc.getType()) {
                            case ADDED:
                                System.err.println("ADDDED: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                                break;
                            case MODIFIED:
                                System.err.println("Modified: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                                break;
                            case REMOVED:
                                System.err.println("Removed: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Is there a way to get actual field that changed inside the document? The code above just returns a Map with refreshed values(I want only value that changed).